# Exists validations with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, validation

Laravel version (7.x).

I have three tables `companies`, `complaint_types` & `complaints`.

The complaints are associated with a `company`.

When a `complaint` is assigned to an `employee` then only he/she can see and enter the complaint status after the visit. Before entering the comments the `complaint` must be validated, otherwise the comment must not be allowed to enter, which is handled upon submitting the form via a hidden field called `complaint_id`.

I have added this validation because I don't want anyone opening the inspect tool, playing with the values and causing the application an error.

Tables:

```
companies:  ->  complaint_types:  ->  complaints:
|-- id          |-- id                |-- id
|-- ...         |-- company_id        |-- complaint_type_id
                |-- ...               |-- ...
```

*Complaint.php:*

```php
public function complaintType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ComplaintType::class);
}
```

*ComplaintType.php:*

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

public function complaints()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Complaint::class);
}
```

*ComplaintController.php:*

```php
private function validate($data)
{
    # variables
    $rules = [
        'complaint_id' => [
            'required', 
            'exists:complaints,id,complaintType.company_id,' . session()->get('COMPANY')
        ],

        -- OR --

        'complaint_id' => [
            'required', 
            'exists:complaints,id,complaint_types.company_id,' . session()->get('COMPANY')
        ],

        ...
    ];

    $messages = [
        'complaint_id.required' => '`Complaint` - Required<br>',
        'complaint_id.exists'   => '`Complaint` could not be identifed<br>',

         ...
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
}
```

**Error**
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'complaintType.company_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) as aggregate FROM complaints WHERE id = 3 AND complaintType.company_id = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, Here is my code:

```
$rules = [
    'complaint_id' => [
    'required',
    function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {
        $Complaint = Complaint::where('id', $value)
            ->whereHas('complaintType', function($query) use($data) {
                return $query->where('company_id', session()->get('COMPANY'));
            })->count();

        if($Complaint <= 0)
            $fail('`Complaint` could not be identified');
    }
],
```

I found the reference here [How can I add a join to a custom exists rule for a laravel validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683667/how-can-i-add-a-join-to-a-custom-exists-rule-for-a-laravel-validator)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify relationship with primary key like:

```
public function complaints(){
return $this->hasMany(Complaint::class, 'complaint_type_id','id');
}
```